# Swift - How can I identify which custom tableview cell has been modified?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have three custom cell types - a cell with a text field, another with a date field, and another with a picker field.

I'm capturing data changes here:

```
 func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("TextField did end editing method called")

        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            currentItem.setObject(itemName, forKey: "itemName")
            .....
            currentItem.setObject(serialNumber, forKey: "serialNumber")

            break

        case 1:
            currentItem.setObject(username, forKey: "username")

            currentItem.setObject(email, forKey: "email")
      ...
            break
```

The "currentItem" is a CKRecord.

This is wrong. The fields (itemName, serialNumber, etc) are strings. They are set in ViewDidLoad with cloud data.

How do I correctly update these fields

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use tag to identify which cell is modified . custom cell  textfield set tag to uniquely identify . in cellforIndexmethod.                                                   func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) { print (_textField.tag)}

Comment: That looks promising, but in `textFieldDidEndEditing`, the tag returned is always zero..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Subin K Kuriakose has said in the comments, you should use the `tag` property of `UITextField` to figure out which text field it is.

You need to set the `tag` property when you create the text field cell. Just keep a variable somewhere and increment it each time a text field is created, and set the `tag` to this variable:

```
textFieldCount += 1
myCustomCell.textField.tag = textFieldCount
```

Something like that, you get the idea.

Now each text field in your table view has a unique tag. In `textFieldDidEndEditing`, you check the tag:

```
switch textField.tag {
    case 1:
        // it's the first text field!
    case 2:
        // it's the second text field!
    case 3:
        // it's the third text field!
    default:
        break
}
```

It's simple!